# Error in eventlog on my SharePoint box System.ServiceModel 4.0.0.0

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, patching, monitoring

I suddenly have this error multiple times in my eventlog.

```
WebHost failed to process a request.
 Sender Information: System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult/28219589
 Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service '/_vti_bin/sts/spsecuritytokenservice.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: This collection already contains an address with scheme http.  There can be at most one address per scheme in this collection. If your service is being hosted in IIS you can fix the problem by setting 'system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/multipleSiteBindingsEnabled' to true or specifying 'system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/baseAddressPrefixFilters'.
Parameter name: item. ---> System.ArgumentException: This collection already contains an address with scheme http.  There can be at most one address per scheme in this collection. If your service is being hosted in IIS you can fix the problem by setting 'system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/multipleSiteBindingsEnabled' to true or specifying 'system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/baseAddressPrefixFilters'.
Parameter name: item
   at System.ServiceModel.UriSchemeKeyedCollection.InsertItem(Int32 index, Uri item)
   at System.Collections.Generic.SynchronizedCollection`1.Add(T item)
   at System.ServiceModel.UriSchemeKeyedCollection..ctor(Uri[] addresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost..ctor(Object singletonInstance, Uri[] baseAddresses)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustServiceHost..ctor(WSTrustServiceContract serviceContract, Uri[] baseAddresses)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPSecurityTokenServiceActiveHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
 Process Name: w3wp
 Process ID: 8356
```

I also had this issue:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4345913/access-denied-errors-after-installing-july-2018-security-rollup-update

I installed the patches and that problem is gone. Could this be related to .NET update?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**To solve this issue, try the following**

- Edit the `web.config` that located in the `SecurityToken` service directory
- Under `<system.serviceModel>` add the below tag

  `<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>`

> **Note:** Take a copy from the `web.config` file before edit to allow the rollback.

For the detail steps, check [Security Token Service cannot be activated due to This collection already contains an address with scheme http](https://blog.devoworx.net/2018/08/11/security-token-service-cannot-be-activated-due-to-this-collection-already-contains-an-address-with-scheme-http/)

Comment: In my case I had to edit the web.config in the STS virtual folder in my IIS website and not in the SecureToken webservice